# Selenium IDE - Verify Text not Present

Tags: selenium

I want to be able to verify (or assert) that text is not present (Ex. assertTextAbsent: "SQL Error").

I would also like to verify/assert that a value is not equal to "0".

Can I do this with Selenium IDE?

Or do I need to use Selenium Web Driver?  (If so, what extension/module works best with PHP?)

Comment: There are commands verifyTextNotPresent and assertTextNotPresent in Selenium IDE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try -

```
verifiedTextNotPresent | exact:??? | |
```

The text you want to verify goes in the '**target**'.

Comment: verityTextNotPresent and assertTextNotPresent are both deprecated in newer versions of Selenium IDE.   The recommendation is to use verifyNotText and assertNotText which requires the Target to be set.  Value is the string you are trying to match.

Answer (score 2):

Text not present can be done with selenium  IDE in easy way and you can do it, by using command `verifyTextNotPresent` and `assertTextNotPresent` in selenium Ide.

```
     Command             | value   | target
    verifyTextNotPresent |         | write text here
```

Answer (score 1):

To Verify / Assert a value not equalling 0 there are two ways

```
verifyEval | ${variable}!==0 | true
verifyEval | ${variable}==0 | false
```

Where ${variable} is the Selenium code for a Variable (You can also use storedVars['variable']

As for checking whether text isn't present (Be confident on what you mean)

the syntax would be

```
verifyNotText
```

However I would also look into verifyNotVisible or VerifyElementNotPresent